# How do I download a file and send a file using Vapor server side swift?

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

1. How do I download a file using server side swift?

I have tried this:

```
let result = try drop.client.get("http://dropcanvas.com/ir4ok/1")
```

but result.body always = 0 elements

2. How do I send a file?

I have tried this

```
drop.get("theFile") { request in 
   let file = NSData(contentsOf: "/Users/bob.zip")
   return file // This fails here
}
```

Comment: try also to join the slackchannel for vapor help

Comment: `result.body` is the right property? here they use `data` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868625/vapor-client-get-transform-and-return-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download a file.

You are on the right track here, but the reason why `result.body` is always empty is because your file service is returning a `302` redirection rather than the file itself. You need to follow this redirection. Here is a simple implementation, specific to your use case only, which works:

```
  var url: String = "http://dropcanvas.com/ir4ok/1"
  var result: Response!
  while true {
    result = try drop.client.get(url)
    guard result.status == .found else { break }
    url = result.headers["Location"]!
  }
  let body = result.body
```

2. Send a file.

The very best method is to save your file in your Vapor app's `Public` directory, and either have your client request the public URL directly, or return a `302` response of your own pointing to it.

If you expressly want to hide the permanent home of the file or e.g. perform authentication then you can return the file from your own route using Vapor's own [FileMiddleware](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/master/Sources/Vapor/Middleware/FileMiddleware.swift) as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

A file can also be returned on an authenticated route like this:

```swift
let fileId: String = "abcd123"

func getFile(on req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {
    let directory = try req.make(DirectoryConfig.self)
    let path = directory.workDir + Constants.filesPath + fileId + ".pdf"

    return try req.streamFile(at: path)
}
```