# Returning a binary file from a custom route (not FileMiddeleware's public folder)

Tags: swift, vapor

I want to return a file via a route that I don't want public. My users will need to use a URL with a unique and one time code. Because of that I don't want to use the public folder via the FileMiddleware.

This is a binary executable, not a text file. I can grab the file as data with FileManager, but it seems like `Future<Data>` is not a valid return type for a route.

After searching StackOverflow, the only thing I've found is this reply to a similar question: [How do I download a file and send a file using Vapor server side swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917803/how-do-i-download-a-file-and-send-a-file-using-vapor-server-side-swift/41974725#41974725)

But that doesn't really fill in much on HOW to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
router.get("customfile") { req -> Future<Response> in
    return try req.streamFile(at: "/path/to/file")
}
```

Comment: Oh cool, so much simpler than I expected. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: What can I do to tell the client how big the file is? When downloading the client just shows how much has downloaded, but not a percentage since it doesn't know how big the file is.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
  app.get("downloadthefile") { req -> Response in
    let filePath = "path/to/the/file"
    let result = req.fileio.streamFile(at: filePath)
    return result
  }
}
```